# ArrayList to Array not displaying the way I want to

Tags: java

```
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    nameList.add("James");
    nameList.add("Joe");
    nameList.add("Josh");
    nameList.add("Bob");
    nameList.add("Billy");
    System.out.println("The names are:\n " + nameList);

    nameList.remove(1);
    System.out.println("Find the index 1 and remove their name from the list:\n "+ nameList);

    nameList.size();
    System.out.println("Currently the ArrayList holds " + nameList.size() +
                        " names after removing the name of index 1" );

    String[] tempArray= new String[nameList.size()];
    tempArray = nameList.toArray(tempArray);

    System.out.println(tempArray); // I want it to display the values of the ArrayList

    }



}
```

The output I'm getting is [Ljava.lang.String;@4554617c when I want it to look like this [James, Josh, Bob, Billy]. New to programming would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things.
Firstly, this code could be reduced.

```
String[] tempArray= new String[nameList.size()];
tempArray = nameList.toArray(tempArray);
```

could become

```
String[] tempArray= nameList.toArray(new String[nameList.size()]);
```

if I am not mistaken.

Secondly, an ArrayList automatically resizes itself with no code needed. How it does that is a whole new question.

And finally. The way objects are printed in Java is that if they are not primaries (int,bool,long,char...), they are printed using their `.toString()` method. On ArrayLists, this `.toString()` method returns a nice pretty representation of the list. But arrays don't define this method, and they instead get printed as some JVM dependent String. Instead, use `Arrays.toString(tempArray)` method. So your print statement would look like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempArray));
```

Don't forget to `import java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: THANK YOU! I thought nobody was going to answer since my post kept getting voted down for some reason.

Comment: @TrushPatel if you think this answer helped you please click the green check mark ✅ in the corner to show the community that this answer helped

Comment: @TrushPatel Your post was downvoted because you could've easily found the solution yourself by googling 'java print array' the first post on google is the question that your question duplicates.